# Is there any standard fileopen dialog in iphone programming?

Tags: iphone, openfiledialog

I want to create application, that will process images(mostly - photographs from mobile camera).

So i need at first to provide the way to open image file from phone memory.
how can i do that?
Sorry for such a stupid question, but i am newbie in iphone programming(yet:)).

P.S. I use xcode, cocoa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIImagePickerController` to get a standard interface for selecting a photo from the user's library or camera roll. Depending on the configuration, it can also be used to capture a new image with the camera. Note however that you get a `UIImage` back, not a file, if you want to upload it somewhere, you will first have to create a file or `NSData` object from the image, using either `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`.